# Copy Distinct values from One Excel Tab to Another Based on Two Conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Construction project system includes safety inspection tool.  Each safety inspection is numbered sequentially.  Running an export reveals that inspection numbers are not unique AND each inspection response creates a row in the output.  The combination of project ID and Inspection # creates a unique ID.  Illustration in Raw Data example below.

[image: Raw Data]

I want to develop an excel formula that, for each DISTINCT / UNIQUE combination of Project ID & Inspection # copies columns A, B, C, and F from the Raw Data into another set of columns.  Result is a distinct list of Inspections and Dates as noted in the second illustration.

[image: Data Results]

Comment: Why the ID K13557 is -2 but not -4?

Answer (score 0):

If your version of Excel has access to dynamic arrays and the new HSTACK() formula, you could use

```
=UNIQUE(HSTACK(A1:C21, F1:F21))
```

To have this formula automatically account for new rows, consider putting the source data in a table and changing the HSTACK arguments to table column references:

```
=HSTACK(Table1[[#All],[InspectionID]:[ProjectName]],Table1[[#All],[date]])
```